# Model::saveMany() performs really slow on CakePHP 2.4

Tags: cakephp, optimization, cakephp-2.4

I am using webgrind with xdebug profiler and I have one AJAX request(hoursList action in Reservations Controller) which calls func to generate reservations(if there are none on selected day) to show. Request takes 20287 miliseconds which is really slow for me. I found out that performance bootleneck here is saveMany() function, which takes 17090 miliseconds to execute. Is there is better way to save many records into database?

Here is function, which generates free reservations, which is in Reservation Model:

```
public function genFreeReservations($queue_id, $sel_date) {
    $this->Queue->recursive = -1;
    $que = $this->Queue->findById($queue_id, array('schedule_id', 'intmins', 'location_id', 'number_id'));
    //$this->Location->recirsive = 2;
    $daytype = $this->Location->Specday->field('specdaytype_id', array(
        "DATE_FORMAT(`spd_datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d')" => $sel_date)
    );
    if (!$daytype)
        $daytype = 0;
    $wday = CakeTime::format('N', $sel_date);
    $this->Location->Interval->recursive = -1;
    $intervals = $this->Location->Interval->find('all', array('conditions' => array('schedule_id' => $que['Queue']['schedule_id'],
            'day' => array(0, $wday),
            'Interval.specdaytype_id' => $daytype
        )
            )
    );
    $this->Queue->Number->recursive = -1;
    $numbers = $this->Queue->Number->findById($que['Queue']['number_id'], array('Number.start', 'Number.end'));
    $number = $numbers['Number']['start'];
    $number_end = $numbers['Number']['end'];
    foreach ($intervals as $interval) {

        $start = CakeTime::fromString($interval['Interval']['start']);
        $end = CakeTime::fromString($interval['Interval']['end']);
        $resToSave = array();
        while ($start < $end) {

            $tend = $start + ($que['Queue']['intmins'] * 60);


            for ($i = 0; $i < $interval['Interval']['workers']; $i++) {

                $resToSave[] = array(
                    'id' => '',
                    'location_id' => $que['Queue']['location_id'],
                    'user_id' => 0,
                    'queue_id' => $queue_id,
                    'ticket_nr' => $number,
                    'code' => '0',
                    'start' => $sel_date . ' ' . CakeTime::format('H:i:s', $start),
                    'end' => $sel_date . ' ' . CakeTime::format('H:i:s', $tend),
                    'deleted' => '0',
                    'modified' => '0',
                    'synchronized' => '1'
                );


                if ($number == $number_end)
                    $number = $numbers['Number']['start'];
                $number++;
            }

            $start = $start + ($que['Queue']['intmins'] * 60);
        }            
        //Performance bootleneck on this function
        $this->saveMany($resToSave);
    }
}
```

saveMany function is at the end of this function.

Comment: how many records are you saving?  saveMany() has never given me an issue before, so I assume there's something else going on.

Comment: There are 780 records here, is there faster way?

Comment: First define slow, then use xdebugs profiler to figure out from where the bottleneck in the php stack *exactly* comes from. But given the amount of rows you save I tend do say it might be normal or the DB is slow. Right now, when using saveMany(), it will trigger all model callbacks for each single record you save. If you don't need callbacks here disable them.

Comment: You could try building out a single Model->query() too.  I don't usually like doing that with user-generated content, but it doesn't look like that's what you're saving.  A single/large multi-INSERT might do the trick better in this case.

Comment: Disabled callbacks, ant it seems it is working bit faster. Will write tommorow If I have any issues.

Comment: Indeed, when disabling callbacks, average request time shrinks from 20 seconds to 5, which is amazing :) Thank you guys. Maybe there are other tweaks, which could help reduce time even more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to optimise saveMany() function by 50% time, all I needed to do is to disable callback functions, which may be executed for each record I save using saveMany():

```
$this->saveMany($resToSave, array('callbacks' => false));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use CASE you can get pretty amazing time reduced result.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `uid` = CASE
    WHEN id = 1 THEN 2952
    WHEN id = 2 THEN 4925
    WHEN id = 3 THEN 1592
    ELSE `uid`
    END
WHERE id  in (1,2,3)
```